# SSIS: execute taks based on value in column in source

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

We are moving data from Oracle to SQL Server via SSIS. The first steps are filling some (about 8 right now) Oracle tables with selections from the existing Oracle application tables.

The 8 Oracle tables should be filled sequentially, so one after the other, but the filling must be able to be initiated from SSIS, one by one (it's a lot of data and things go wrong!) or all in 1 go (again, one after the other). So we made 9 SSIS packages for this, 8 for filling oracle tables and 1 that calls the 8 packages sequentially. All 8 packages call Oracle procedures, that are contained in 1 Oracle package, to fill the tables.

For 1 of the 8 Oracle tables we made (oracle) parallel jobs to fill the table (for performance sake, via the Oracle job scheduler) . Drawback of Oracle job scheduler parallel execution is that the 'mother' job is finished as soon as all the child jobs are submitted (not completed). So the status wether all subjobs are finished, is put in an Oracle table/column/field (eg FINISHED = 1) through another Oracle procedure. For the next SSIS package to run, the table/column/field has to be a certain value (eg FINISHED = 1), before the next SSIS package can run (to fill the next Oracle table).

I have searched quite a bit, but cannot find a solution on how to do this in SSIS from A to Z. Some say via script task but do not provide screenshots or an example. I am absolutely no expert in SSIS, I just know some basic stuff.

Thank you in advance!

PS: I am looking for a loop-constuct because we don't know how long it wil take for the Oracle scheduler jobs to complete (we test with 1000 rows, up to 20 million)

Comment: Please explain "made parallel jobs to fill the table" - do you mean you made SQL Server Agent jobs? Are you saying you need to implement the FINISHED=1 logic but you don't know how?

Comment: The parallelism to fill the Oracle table was made via the Oracle job scheduler, so all is handled in the Oracle database. The only thing SSIS knows is when the value in column FINISHED in table JOB_STATUS has the value of 1 (in the Oracle database) and then it should fire  the next SSIS package to fill the next Oracle table.

Comment: Basically you need to run an Oracle command inside an execute SQL task in SSIS. This command checks the table in an endless WHILE loop. When the table has the required value you BREAK out of it. Don’t forget to SLEEP inside the loop.